# Openfire prebind + robbiehanson/XMPPFramework using BOSH not working

Tags: iphone, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

We're trying to implement `XMPP` over `BOSH` for our product. The `Strophe.js` javascript library works fine for our needs on the WWW site. We request a prebind, it's delivered and then we use Strophe's 'attach' method to start our session - then we're able to update presence and send/receive messages. On the iOS side of things, we're using the robbiehanson `XMPPFramework` which includes a BOSH transport, but there's no attach method. Below is some of my grief with trying to get this to work.

I prebind, get my sid/jid/rid, then set the internal logic inside the bosh transport and other files to say that we're already connected. Then if I try to update presence, including the given SID, I send:

> BOSH: SEND[1248340729] = < body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" sid="568a3ae9" ack="1248340728" rid="1248340729">< presence>< /presence>< /body>

but don't get any reply atall. That's the last of it. If I try to update presence without specifying SID, I send:

> BOSH: SEND[1064338700] = < body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" ack="1064338699" rid="1064338700">< presence>< /presence>< /body>

and get back:

> BOSH: RECD[1342811427] = < body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" authid="9ef0ccdb" sid="9ef0ccdb" secure="true" requests="2" inactivity="300" polling="5" wait="60">< stream:features>< mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"> < mechanism>PLAIN< /mechanism>< /mechanisms>< compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress">< method>zlib< /method>< /compression>< bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/>< session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/>< /stream:features>< /body>

which looks like a connection affirmation, or a connection challenge stanza expecting me to respond with the PLAIN information - but this has already been established with the prebind. If it is a connection affirmation, then the next lines don't make sense. If using the SID provided by the connection string above, as if it's an affirmation (I'm not sure), these are the next lines:

> BOSH: SEND[1342811427] = < body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" sid="9ef0ccdb" rid="1342811428">< iq type="set">< bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind">< resource>api< /resource>< /bind>< /iq>< /body>
>
> BOSH: RECD[1342811427] = < body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>< iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" to="chat.*.com/9ef0ccdb">< bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind">< resource>api< /resource>< /bind>< error code="401" type="auth">< not-authorized xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>< /error>< /iq>< /body>

I'm not authorized. Now if I try using the SID that was negotiated during prebind, the last two lines are different:

> BOSH: SEND[1172064714] = < body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" sid="27e3745b" rid="1172064715">< iq type="set">< resource>api< /resource>< /bind>< /iq>< /body>
>
> BOSH: RECD[1172064714] = < body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind">< /body>

an empty response. Then if I try updating my presence again, it gives me a literal `404` page saying there's an invalid SID. When I was using the SID provided by openfire, if I re-tried the presence update, it would just keep on giving me `401 not authorized`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get XMPPFramework with BOSH support? XMPPFramework works only with plain TCP connection